# Only Getting Static When Streaming Radio to Icecast2 Streaming Audio Server

Tags: sox, icecast2

I am trying to create a POC for a potential client. I need to be able to take a radio signal and convert into into a format that people can listen to on their phones. I am doing this with rtl_fm, Sox, ezstream, and icecast2. I can successfully do this with .ogg file conversion, but only get static when doing MP3.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4nIDjcXO0A&list=PLe9pq_93u_1WgQZzO2YmMcDf4DmdsC7PE
```

My theory is that I have setup the settings wrong for MP3 in the Sox conversion. Another idea is that I should be pushing this to .mpu streaming URL instead of .mp3.

Here is my ezstream.xml settings:

[image: ezstream.xml configuration]

Here is the command that I am issuing (taking the radio input from rtl_fm and converting it in Sox then having ezstream push it to icecast2):
[image: commands to stream]

Here is the command response (it is working):
[image: command response]

And here is my stream with local intranet URL:
[image: local stream]

All I get is static!!! When I convert some things, I get a weird, ghostly sound. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

I have already got this working with .ogg streaming. Unfortunately that does not work well for iPhones, so I need an MP3 solution. I have changed the configurations, some causing the stream to fail. Others making little to no difference.

Comment: I actually got this working but need to do some changes to get it working with UDP streaming.